# SSIS check if date is certain value

Tags: sql, mysql, ssis

I have a table in MYSQL that have a datetime field, whenever there is no value it puts this kind of date: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
I am trying to use SSIS to transfer the data to MSSQL but I get an error about date range.
So I tried doing data conversion from database timestamp to database date and I get it to look like 1/1/0001 but not sure how to continue from here, I want to do a derived column that if the date is 1/1/0001 then change it to null and if it's not just set the date normally.
Is it possible? if so how?

Tried to create a derived column but kept getting error about token issue and if I put single mark quotation I get a different error about the ? in the expression.

Comment: Can you select the column from MYSQL and convert it to a varchar?  Then it wont change/default to the datetime of all 0,  the null value should come over as null, and the dates that are valid would still be valid to be inserted into MSSQL date column.